# Calculate Cyclomatic Complexity for Javascript

Tags: javascript, metrics, cyclomatic-complexity

Are there any tools available for calculating Cyclomatic Complexity in Javascript?

I've found it a very helpful metric in the past while working on server side code, and would like to be able to use it for the client side Javascript I write.

Answer (score 27):

I helped write a tool to perform software complexity analysis on JavaScript projects:

[complexity-report](https://github.com/escomplex/complexity-report)

It reports a bunch of different complexity metrics: lines of code, number of parameters, cyclomatic complexity, cyclomatic density, Halstead complexity measures, the maintainability index, first-order density, change cost and core size.

It is released under the MIT license and built using Node.js and the [Esprima](http://esprima.org/) JavaScript parser. It can be installed via npm, like so:

```
npm i -g complexity-report
```

Comment: This is great tool. It would be even more useful if it can be used as grunt task. Then we can see this report at each build!

Comment: Just found grunt task for this tool: https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-complexity

Comment: As of 2017 this solution is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 14):

For completeness in the answers, I was looking for the same tool some time ago and didn't find anything that worked well for visualization so I wrote [plato](http://github.com/jsoverson/plato)

Sample reports for :

- [jquery](http://jsoverson.github.com/plato/examples/jquery/)
- [grunt](http://jsoverson.github.com/plato/examples/grunt/)
- [marionettejs](http://jsoverson.github.com/plato/examples/marionette/)

It uses phil's complexity-report (mentioned above) and also aggregates data from jshint (and eventually, others).

Answer (score 11):

[JSHint](https://jshint.com/about/) recently [added support](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/pull/593) for calculating code metrics.

You can set maximum values for:

- [`maxparams`](https://jshint.com/docs/options/#maxparams) - the number of formal parameters allowed
- [`maxdepth`](https://jshint.com/docs/options/#maxdepth) - how deeply nested code blocks should be
- [`maxstatements`](https://jshint.com/docs/options/#maxstatements) - the number of statements allowed per function
- [`maxcomplexity`](https://jshint.com/docs/options/#maxcomplexity) - the maximum cyclomatic complexity

#### Examples

*Maximum number of formal parameters allowed per function*

```js
/*jshint maxparams:3 */

function login(request, onSuccess) {
  // ...
}

// JSHint: Too many parameters per function (4).
function logout(request, isManual, whereAmI, onSuccess) {
  // ...
}
```

*Maximum number of nested code blocks allowed per function*

```js
/*jshint maxdepth:2 */

function main(meaning) {
  var day = true;

  if (meaning === 42) {
    while (day) {
      shuffle();

      if (tired) { // JSHint: Blocks are nested too deeply (3).
          sleep();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*Maximum number of statements allowed per function*

```js
/*jshint maxstatements:4 */

function main() {
  var i = 0;
  var j = 0;

  // Function declarations count as one statement. Their bodies
  // don't get taken into account for the outer function.
  function inner() {
    var i2 = 1;
    var j2 = 1;

    return i2 + j2;
  }

  j = i + j;
  return j; // JSHint: Too many statements per function. (5)
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Since cyclomatic complexity is evaluated counting the number of keyword
"if, switch, while for break" etc.. every tools that works with C will do the job, like
sourcemonitor:
http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html

Actually, on javascript the more you try to modulize your code, the more you will slow it down, so take it with a grain of salt ;)

EDIT:
I **Really** can't understand what's going on on this answer, I get another downvote, when in my answer I tell a good tool for calculating cyclomatic complexity in javascript,
and this in particular works very well.

For the second assertion, mine is a comment that comes from experience, I never tell *don't modulize your js code*, I only tell to *make attention in doing it*, because often there is a tradeoff with speed, and when I talk of speed I mean that 2 different slowdown can happen: at *download time* and at *execution time* (and in slow device like pda/smartphone this is important).

Since tools like this often drive developer into writing more code trying to chase the smaller index possible,
but in js more code unfortunately means that slowdowns can happen, and the **overuse** of these tools is bad.
Surelly these tools can give you hints of **where** your code can be improved, but you've to master how to use the tool and not blindy rely on it.

So if you downvote me again, please write a comment in which you explain why you do so, the discussion can only benefit from this, thank you and sorry for the vent.

Comment: Modularizing your code slow's it down? How does that make sense?

Comment: Actually it has sense, since in javascript writing more code means more downloading time (is a tradeoff that all knows btw), I wrote javascript code that runs in very slow architecture so, for me, this is an important factor. I didn't say "don't modulize", I just say "be warned"

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but it doesn't seem like modularized slows down your code in javascript is enough to justify writing your code in a procedural style.  But I guess that is a case by case basis.

Comment: You also should be setting "Expires" headers far into the future for your javascript so that the client browser will cache it. This reduces the hit that recurring visitors have to deal with when they visit your site.

Answer (score 6):

The new version of http://jshint.com is out and has a very good cyclomatic complexity calculator

Answer (score 3):

You can use the ccm tool from [ARCHIVE of blunck.info](https://web.archive.org/web/20150219013605/http://www.blunck.info/ccm.html) or the github repo [jonasblunck/ccm](https://github.com/jonasblunck/ccm)

It supports JavaScript, C/C++ and C#. It's free, runs on Windows (can be run on Linux and Mac OS X as well - using the Mono framework).

Answer (score 3):

There's now also Yardstick: https://github.com/calmh/yardstick

It tries to calculate cyclomatic complexity for idiomatic Javascript, handling more cases than for example jscheckstyle.