# What is an easy way to calculate the CRAP metric in my Javascript build process?

Tags: javascript, build-process, code-metrics

I'm a fan of the [CRAP](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=215899) metric, and use it to monitor code quality for my [C#](http://crap4net.codeplex.com/) and [Java](http://www.crap4j.org/) projects.

I'd like to do the same for my growing Javascript codebase.

Is there an existing process that makes this easy to integrate into my Javascript build process?

Comment: you can use [jscoverage](http://siliconforks.com/jscoverage/) and [jsmeter](http://jsmeter.info/)

Comment: I've investigated jsmeter & jscoverage; but neither output a useful XML format.

Comment: I've created a tool to calculate the CRAP score of a JS or TS project based on a project's test coverage report: https://www.npmjs.com/package/crap-score

Answer (score 1):

The CRAP formula is:

```
var complexity = ...; //cyclomatic complexity of a method
var coverage   = ...; //test code coverage for the method
var crap = Math.pow(complexity,2) * Math.pow(1 – coverage/100,3) + complexity;
```

So, you need to [calculate the cyclomatic complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100645/calculate-cyclomatic-complexity-for-javascript) and [calculate the test code coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249/are-there-any-good-javascript-code-coverage-tools) (or [here](http://siliconforks.com/jscoverage/)).

Comment: I'm aware of the formula; I was hoping there was a pre-existing tool available that applied it to Javascript.  Looks like extending a test running tool like JSTestDriver is the most promising option available.

Answer (score 0):

jshint calculates the cyclomatic complexity, see http://www.jshint.com/docs/ parameter maxcomplexity.
I don't know, how you can retrieve the results, but you might look into the jshint sources.
Hope that helps